# Select option maximum displayed values

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

is there any way to set the maximum number of option tags and if this number is exceeded then the scroll bar is displayed?

I've tried to set this

```
<select size="3">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

But it will display instantly 3 options and scroll bar. I'm no more able to click and open dropdown with all these options.

I've tried to do this with JavaScript

```
<select onFocus="maxSize">
...
...
</select>

function maxSize(e){
  e.target.size = "10"
}
```

But result is almost the same.With that function I'm able to click and open the dropdown ,but after choosing one of the options dropdown won't close.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide parenthesis when using [onevent handler attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) like `on"whatever"()`

Also the event object won't get passed to your event handler so you should pass `this` instead which would then hold a reference to element which triggered that event

```html
<select size="3" onfocus="maxSize(this)">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>

<script>
  function maxSize(el) {
    el.size = "10"
  }
</script>
```